# Why is my cat blinking?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

One of my Outer Barrier Wall Guardian Felines, currently attached to its Bloodlust Distance-Minimization Chain, is blinking between no background and a light brown background. I looked on [the wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2010:Status_icon), but the only similar icon is "prone", and that doesn't blink.

It has nothing out of the ordinary listed on the wounds screen; everything is white with no conditions listed. I'm running the "curses_640x300" tileset on 0.31.12 with the MinimalDF mod, which AFAIK doesn't touch anything graphical.

Comment: Are you *sure* the cat has never suffered any wounds? In my experience, sometimes scars alone are enough to cause that flashing color (it happens to my companions in adventure mode all the time).

Comment: And additionally, thank you for bringing up MinimalDF. I had been trying (unsuccessfully) to relocate that mod for some time.

Comment: Pretty close to certain. I don't have any reports involving the cat in question, and I'm only coming up on a year of time so I suspect that it would show something in the wound screen, though I'm not sure if a wound would have healed on its own in that time.

Also, I got my copy of MinimalDF on [DFFD](http://dffd.wimbli.com/file.php?id=2979).

Comment: Any potential Forgotten Beast or Titan Syndromes running around?

Comment: Not that I can see in the unit list.

Comment: Is this a constant thing?  It might be standing on an item which gives it that background color?

Comment: Have you tried loo[k]ing to see if it's sharing the tile with another item/creature?

Comment: In RL, cats usually blink to show deference, or love. My friend calls them kitten kisses. Maybe you should get one of your dwarves to 'kiss' back.

Comment: Curious indeed.  I thought of asking for a screenshot, but perhaps it would be better just to upload a save to DFFD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you've described the problem, the best bet is that it's continually switching between standing and prone. My first guess was that you actually have two cats on the same tile, one beneath the other, but then you'd get the spinning green line as it switched from one to the other. So that's not it.

As for WHY it's continually falling over, I'm not sure we have enough information. Cats don't eat or drink, so it's not collapsing in hunger or thirst. Extreme pain or missing limbs would appear in the <kbd>v</kbd>iew unit -> <kbd>w</kbd>ounds menu. They probably will NOT appear in the <kbd>v</kbd>iew unit -> <kbd>z</kbd>tatus screen, because animals don't produce diagnosis tasks when they're wounded.